# Only Drop & Create could resolve issue with stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a stored procedure that takes two arguments an ID value and a code. The body of the sp has several queries but only one will execute each time based on the input code.

```
Create Proc sp_Test (@DocumentID int, @Code int) AS

IF @Code = 1
BEGIN
    Select *
    From SomeTable WITH (nolock)
    WHERE ID = @DocumentID
END

ELSE IF @Code =2
BEGIN
    --This query has bad performance
    Select *
    From SomeTable2 WITH (nolock)
    WHERE ID = @DocumentID
END

Else IF @Code = 3
BEGIN
    Select *
    From SomeTable3 WITH (nolock)
    WHERE ID = @DocumentID
END
```

This stored procedure is called by external app, and some times (random intervals might be days might be hours) it returns time-out on the application and the only way to fix this problem is to Drop and recreate the sp.

The procedure will stuck only on the 2ed query which has worse performance than the others. When the process is stacked, if I try to execute the query from management studio the query is stack in execution as well. This query takes less than 1 second to execute and I am really baffled what could cause this.

I tested with clear cashe and statists (to check execution plan) and local parameters (to check parameter sniffing) but I could not figure something out.

Do you have any idea what might cause this behavior?

Comment: Lack of indexing and (ab)use of the `NOLOCK` hint?

Comment: Not to mention that the prefix `sp_` is reserved, by Microsoft, for **S**pecial / **S**ystem **P**rocedures. It should *not* be used for User Procedures. Doing so comes with a performance cost and the risk of your Procedure simply not working one day after an update/upgrade. Either use a different prefix or (possibly better) no prefix at all. [Is the sp_ prefix still a no-no?](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix)

Comment: you could try to add OPTION(RECOMPILE) to better handle various parameters sent to the procedure. But the best would be to check indexes

Comment: By dropping the object you are forcing a recompile and a new execution plan cached based on the parameters suppliered on the next execution. Presumably the queries in your question are very simplified; do all return the same resultset?

Comment: @ThomA Thank you for your answers. Yes, we do not use prefix sp_ I just typed a Pseudocode for the question. Regarding the "bad indexing" or nolock, how could they cause the mentioned behavior? I could expect to delay (although it executes in less than a sec) but this stucks in execution.

Comment: @Stu All the queries returns the same results just from different tables. What baffles me is not that the recreation makes a new plan, but how is it stuck? I am thinking that the process is stuck and the drop of the sp just kills the session. But How could it be?

Comment: Queries don't get *stuck* but they do get *blocked*, waiting on other processes to release locks or free resources, you need to see what the SPID is waiting on. Eg a bad plan could be escalating to a table lock which it is waiting on etc

Answer (score 0):

The problem is on the "SomeTable2" table. Try to observe the frequency of INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE on this table. If it is very frequent, the table and indexes are often restructured and the statistics for creating the execution plan are then out of date. In such a case, it may be advisable to schedule a maintenance plan and reorganize/rebuild the indexes. I recommend checking out https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/reorganize-and-rebuild-indexes?view=sql-server-ver16 or https://solutioncenter.apexsql.com/why-when-and-how-to-rebuild-and-reorganize-sql-server-indexes/

Comment: The table is properly indexed and it's execution takes less than 1 second. It's just more costly than the others but it is excepted. I cannot understand how is it possible for the process to stuck.. not delayed.. stuck!